# Call startActivityForResult from fragment doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make the call `startActivityForResult` inside the fragment in order to capture a photo from camera. The problem is that the method `onActivityResult` of the fragment is called, the `ImageView` is updated with the receiving bitmap but immediately the fragment is removed an it is replace with the previous one. Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

```
private void addButtonListener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    buttonAddFoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View button) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mListener.setIdButton(button.getId());
            //mListener.takeImageFromCamera();
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                 startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             }
        }

    });
}

@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("FRAGMENT DENTRO ON ACTIVITY RESULT1","");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        this.circleImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        Log.d("FRAGMENT DENTRO ON ACTIVITY RESULT2","");

     }

}
```

Comment: Provide us the source code to help you

Comment: How can I add my source code?

Comment: To learn how to add code http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: I have to make another question with the same title in order to attach my source code?

Comment: You can edit your question and then add source code

Comment: Are you using the Support Library fragments? What version of the Support Library are you using?

Comment: My fragment is a simple Fragment, I am not using the support library fragment.

Comment: anyway I'm using the support v7 appcompat, are you referring that?

Comment: Try getting rid of the super call.

Comment: I have already tried but it does not work.

Comment: I just resolve. The problem was that, in the hosted activity I have the OnConnected method related to goolgeApiClient, and it seems that after that android call the onActivityresult of my fragment, it after call the onConnected method, and inside this method I add the fragment before the one that is the cause of this question.